# Web calendar sync with android calendar

Tags: android, calendar

Is there any web calendar say FullCalendar which can provide sync to a default android Google calendar? 
We tried this one but it is manual syncing, once the user login in the our app then we will download all events from web server to local calendar. But if there are some update from fullcalendar or even android calendar there are no syncing.

Anyone knows if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The web version of Google Calendar ( https://www.google.com/calendar/ )
will sync automatically to your Android Calendar.
GL, hope this helps